# How Can I Map Select With AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I use AutoMapper to mapping. I needed to use Distinct & Select. But now my mapping is not working and says "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping"

What can i do?

```
        cfg.CreateMap<SearchHistory, SearchDashBoardDto>();

        var searchList = _unitOfWork.SearchRepository.GetSearchHistory(userId, sessionId)
                                .Select(x => new { x.SearchText, x.Url })
                                .Distinct();

        return _mapper.Map<List<SearchDashBoardDto>>(searchList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to map an anonymous type to a DTO. Older versions of Automapper would support this via options to attempt to resolve unknown mappings but that gradually got phased out. I believe there is still support for `DynamicMap()` which should work /w Dmitriy's answer.

Automapper can manage this entirely using `ProjectTo`. You will need to provide it a MapperConfiguration with how to translate a SearchHistory into a SearchDashBoardDto, *and* ensure that your search repository is returning `IQueryable<SearchHistory>` rather than something like `IEnumerable<SearchHistory>`.

Assuming your DTO has a SearchText and Url column with the same naming convention as the Entity, an example with a local configuration:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<SearchHistory, SearchDashBoardDto>());

var searchList = _unitOfWork.SearchRepository
    .GetSearchHistory(userId, sessionId)
    .ProjectTo<SearchDashBoardDto>(config)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

The mapper configuration is needed for the `ProjectTo` extension method. This can be configured centrally and passed in as a dependency, or constructed on demand or via a factory method. (I typically place them as static methods on the View Models)

Edit: Alternatively, if you are going through the trouble of using `Select` to an anonymous type, you may as well just populate your ViewModel:

```
var searchList = _unitOfWork.SearchRepository.GetSearchHistory(userId, sessionId)
    .Select(x => new SearchDashBoardDto
    { 
        SearchText = x.SearchText, 
        Url = x.Url 
    }).Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

If your repository is returning `IEnumerable<SearchHistory>` or the like this won't work, and it certainly won't be ideal from a performance perspective as it would be returning the entire search history entities. (Where you only care about 2 fields, and distinct results) The above can help build more efficient queries to let the DB call return just the data you want to return. If the repository is returning `IEnumerable` or `IList` etc. rather than `IQueryable`, then my recommendation would be either to move this across to using `IQueryable` or get rid of the repository all-together and just use the `DbContext`/`DbSet`s.

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
_unitOfWork.SearchRepository.GetSearchHistory(userId, sessionId)
                                .Select(x => new { x.SearchText, x.Url })
                                .Distinct()
                                .Select(s => _mapper.Map<SearchDashBoardDto>(s))
                                .ToList()
```